# How to load data of a relation ship (many to many) ASP.Net Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i have a model called User and another with name SecurityGroup, these models have a relationship many to many in the database and exists a table for that relationship with name UsersSecurity...Ok, when i Scaffolded the model the model users autogenerate this attribute
`public virtual ICollection<UsersSecurity> UsersSecurities { get; set; }`. I think this attribute can store the records with relation but when i use the debug view in a breakpoint i realizes that the attribute it's empty
This is the view in the database of user with UserID = 2
[image]

As you can see, there is two records with UserID = 2

But in the debug view in Visual Studio i notice this:
[image: Debub breakpoint]

The attribute `UsersSecurities` have nothing inside, in the upper part of the photo you can see i'm searching the user with Id = 2, Line: `var sc = _context.Users.Find(2);`, ¿How can i bring the SecurityGroups associated to it in that variable? (I think there's information missing, just ask me for the information neccesary, please i reallly need solve this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lazy-loading, you must use `Include` for fetch related entites.

```
_context.Users.Include(u => u.UsersSecurities)....
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem but i have one more question, do you know how to add another one record in a user? For example, i wanna add one UserSecurity in that list, when i do _context.add(User), that add a new user but a want to add the sublevel _context.Add(User.UserSecurity)

Comment: if `User` has usersecurities, UserSecurities will be insert too when you do context.add(User)